# Save excel formula in the DataFrame and then write it to excel

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

There is a small data frame df.
I want to write it to Excel so that column B contains formula: B=A+C

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(3,3)), columns=list('ABC'))
df['B']='=RC[-1]+RC[1]'
with pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\belose\Downloads\output.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='w')as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1',  index=False)
```

Excel then doesn't recognize the contents of the column B at all and sends the error message.
[image]

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for the formula:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(3,3)), columns=list('ABC'))
df['B'] = '=INDIRECT("R[0]C[-1]", 0)+INDIRECT("R[0]C[1]", 0)'

with pd.ExcelWriter(r'output.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='w')as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1',  index=False)
```

Output:

[image]

You could also improvise this by giving the position of the 'A' and 'C' columns relative from 'B' instead of -1 and 1.

```
df['B'] = '=INDIRECT("R[0]C[%s]", 0)+INDIRECT("R[0]C[%s]", 0)'%\
          (df.columns.get_loc('A') - df.columns.get_loc('B'),
           df.columns.get_loc('C') - df.columns.get_loc('B'))
```

Comment: just wondering, why Excel accepts formulas from Pandas only via Indirect?